# Formik's "isValid" reporting true even though validation schema reports an error

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

It looks like Formik's flag "isValid" is set to `true` in certain cases, even if the form values should not be considered valid. I have a working codesandbox example below where this is showcased.

https://m229l.csb.app/

The validation schema that I am using for my form is the following:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape(
  {
    heading: Yup.string().required('Heading required.'),
    image: Yup.string().when('placeholder', {
      is: '',
      then: Yup.string().required(
        'Please either choose an image, or a placeholder.'
      ),
      otherwise: Yup.string(),
    }),
    placeholder: Yup.string().when('image', {
      is: '',
      then: Yup.string().required(
        'Please either choose an image, or a placeholder.'
      ),
      otherwise: Yup.string(),
    }),
  },
  [['image', 'placeholder']]
);
```

When outputting Formik's `isValid` flag, it is `true` for the following values:

```
{ heading: 'a', image: '', placeholder: '' }
```

The schema states that *one of* the fields "image" or "placeholder" must be present, but in the case above, they are not. Yet the `isValid` flag is `true`.

When testing this manually with Yup, I get the expected result though:

```
validationSchema.validate(values).then(...).catch(...);
```

This can further be seen in the codesandbox. What am I missing here? Is there more happening behind the scenes when Formik is validating the values?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue hence along with `formik.isValid`, I used an another attribute `formik.touched` and considered the form to be **valid** only when **`formik.isValid = true`** and **`Object.keys(formik.touched).length > 0` (at least some fields should be touched)** as below:

```
const isFormValid = formik.isValid && Object.keys(formik.touched).length > 0; // WITH lodash: formik.isValid && !_.isEmpty(formik.touched)
if (isFormValid) {
 // NOW SUBMIT THE FORM OR DO YOUR NEXT STEP
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `validateOnMount` to formik so that it validates the initial values:

```
<Formik 
  validateOnMount={true} 
  initialValues={initialValues}
  validationSchema={validationSchema} 
>
// your form
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying [`validateOnMount=true`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#validateonmount-boolean) doesn't trigger validations when you manually reset form using `resetForm()`.

In Formik v2, you can call [`validateForm()`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#validateform-values-any--promiseformikerrorsvalues) after your `resetForm()` to rerun validations.

Usage:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const formRef = useRef();
const initialValues = { foo: "", bar: "" };
const appliedValues = { foo: "bar", bar: "foo" };

const someFunc = () => {
    formRef.current.resetForm({ values: { ...initialValues, ...appliedValues} });
    setTimeout(() => formRef.current.validateForm());
    // note1: resetForm() is not returning Promise, therefore we cannot use .then() chaining, and we need to use setTimeout to delay the validations until form is done resetting. Else, the validation will happen before reset is complete.
    // note2: validateForm() is a promise function, so you can use .then() to chain with other formik functions.
};

<Formik
    innerRef={formRef}
    validateOnMount // <-- use this so it works for initial render
    initialValues={initialValues}
    ...
>
```